# Product grid not load ---- Unable to process binding Knockout.js magento 2

Tags: magento2

Facing issue when loading product edit page:

> knockout.js:3012

Uncaught ReferenceError:

Unable to process binding

"if:
 function(){return label }"
Message: label is not defined

```
at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:55)
at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3989)
at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
at init (knockout.js:3988)
at knockout.js:2989
at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1249)
at knockout.js:2988
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing the same.

Comment: yes i was missing label tag in my xml file

Comment: what was the location of xml file? I'm seeing the same issue with amasty extension and they say it's working on their end.